# How to anchor image links? The relative links work but root directory based links do not work

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

The following works in my website on localhost:

```html
<img src="../../../../../../Assets/Images/Architecture/America/Misouri/St-Louis/St-Louis-Basilica/st-louis-02.jpg" />
```

This does not work:

```html
<img src="/Assets/Images/Architecture/America/Misouri/St-Louis/St-Louis-Basilica/st-louis-02.jpg" />
```

In Dreamweaver links are set relative to the document, and the image folder is set to `<local directory>/Assets/Images`.

I want to get the root relative links to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `/` before `Assets`. It will make the path relative to root folder.

So the tag will become

```html
<img src="Assets/Images/Architecture/America/Misouri/St-Louis/St-Louis-Basilica/st-louis-02.jpg" />
```